# O que são refresh token, access tokens e grant type?

Tags: segurança, token

Estava pesquisando sobre segurança em APIs REST e encontrei os termos *refresh tokens*, *access tokens* e *grant type* se referindo a forma como os tokens funcionam e como o cliente solicita os recursos

O que são e quais as suas diferenças?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Access Tokens** - É um tipo de credencial que você pode utilizar para dar permissão
a sistemas externos interagirem com a sua aplicação. Como você bem citou por exemplo,
seu conjunto de APIs Rest só poderiam ser consumidas por meio de um identificador que
você mesmo oferece para seus sistemas parceiros. Esse ID é o Access Token. Um exemplo
prático disso, é quando você precisa consumir alguma API do Google/Facebbok.

**Refresh Tokens** - Ocasionalmente, você pode querer verificar de tempos em tempos o ID
(Access Token) que aquele sistema que está consumindo a sua API possui. Pode ser por
motivos de segurança, monetização da sua API ou mesmo a frequência de uso da api. Funciona da seguinte forma: Você dá para o seu parceiros 2 chaves: 1) O Access Token
(com tempo de vida curto) e 2) O Refresh Token (Usado para pegar um novo Access Token).
Dessa forma, quando o seu parceiro requisitar a sua aplicação, ele envia essas 2 chaves
e o seu sistema verifica se o Access Token está expirado. Caso esteja, você gera um
novo Access Token usando o Refresh Token que o parceiro lhe enviou.

**Grant Types** - Quando você ouvir esse termo, referece-se as maneiras que um sistema
externo possui para obter acesso a um Access Token para consumo da sua API. Podendo ser eles:

1. Authorization code
2. Implicit
3. Resource owner credentials
4. Client credentials
5. Refresh token

Todos esses conceitos da sua pergunta, fazem parte da especificação do OAuth 2.0 e você
pode obter mais detalhes aqui ([OAuth 2.0 Docs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)) e aqui ([OAuth 2.0 Workflow Vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPbvxxslDTU)).

Comment: Show,
Aí no caso o que sempre muda de tempo em tempo é o access_token.

No caso para salvar os dados no banco de dados, eu preciso salvar o refresh_token que é a chave de acesso para conseguir um novo access_token.

E o access_token é necessário salvar no BD? Ou simplesmente posso só usar o refresh_token com o código para solicitar um novo access_token e assim obtê-lo para acessar as informações?

Answer (score 3):

Access tokens são credenciais usadas para acessar recursos protegidos.

Refresh tokens são credenciais usadas para obter um novo acess token.

Grant type é usado quando o cliente quer receber access token sem transmitir informações importantes, como o client secret.

[Access tokens e Refresh tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4)

[Grant type](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/jwt-bearer/)