# Qual a vantagem em usar um Refresh Token ao invés de somente o Access Token?

Tags: segurança, token

Eu entendo a diferença entre **Access Token** e **Refresh Token**, já existe uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/341018/100416) sobre isso aqui no SOpt. Também vi questões do SOen envolvendo [o uso do Refresh Token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26834685/8839059).

Entre

1. passar um **Access Token** de vida longa; ou
2. passar um **Access Token** de vida curta e um **Refresh Token** de vida longa

Por que eu escolheria a segunda opção? Quais as vantagens dela sob a primeira opção?

Usar um **Refresh Token** me parece uma boa ideia, mas se o *token* de vida longa for comprometido em ambos os casos, o problema seria o mesmo, já que com um *token* de renovação eu conseguiria obter um *token* de acesso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vantagem é uma maior segurança. Mas é claro que isso dependerá da forma que você implementar. Obviamente não é pelo fato de usar dois *tokens* que a sua aplicação magicamente tornar-se-á mais segura. :)

---

Antes de tudo, vale entender que utilizar somente um *stateless* token para garantir acesso à sua aplicação é, muitas vezes, inseguro, já que pode ser roubado — e isso dificilmente pode ser impedido, já que pode ser eventualmente feito a nível de hardware.

Assim, criar unicamente um *access token* com um grande período de expiração (como o período de uma semana) é um "suicídio de segurança", já que (na maioria das aplicações) não são implementados meios de **cancelar** um token antes do fim de seu período de expiração. Portanto, se um token for roubado, no geral não é possível fazer nada até que ele seja expirado. E isso traz problemas.

Então, enfrenta-se um dilema para resolver esse problema:

- Criar unicamente os tokens de acesso com um **tempo de vida muito longo** — o que **não** seria viável a nível de segurança, já que caso o token fosse roubado, não haveríamos como cancelá-lo em tempo hábil.
- Criar unicamente os tokens de acesso com um **tempo de vida muito curto** — o que **não** seria viável a nível de experiência de usuário, já que no caso do roubo desse token, não haveríamos como cancelá-lo em tempo hábil.
- Criar um tipo de ***blacklist*** que te permite listar tokens que você não quer que sejam mais acessíveis, mesmo antes da expiração. Mas isso **não** me parece uma boa opção se você está utilizando um *stateless token* em primeiro lugar, já que traz inúmeros problemas. O maior deles: acabar com a necessidade de usar um *stateless token*, pois deixa de ser *stateless* no momento em que a cada requisição você precisa verificar se o token é válido ou não. Sinceramente, nesse caso vale mais a pena recorrer às boas e velhas sessões.
- Criar um mecanismo com autenticação a base de dois tokens, um *access token* e um *refresh token*. E este é mais viável, já que nos permite criar um token verificável com grande tempo de vida (o *refresh token*) e um token para acessar de fato a nossa aplicação com um curto tempo de vida (o *access token*).

Portanto, nota-se que o *access token* é usado para dar acesso de fato à aplicação, apesar de ter um tempo de vida curto. Assim, a aplicação verificará a validade do *refresh token* para gerar um novo *access token* ao usuário, sem a necessidade de pedir por suas credenciais.

Agora cabe a você decidir como implementará isso. Para o *refresh token*, qualquer meio é válido.

O que eu costumo fazer é colocar um campo `count` no *payload* do `requestToken`, que deve ser igual ao valor `count` do registro de um usuário no banco de dados. Se o número for **diferente**, considero que o `refreshToken` é inválido e mando o usuário fazer login para gerar os dois tokens novamente.

Nesse caso, se um token do usuário for roubado, ele mesmo poderá solicitar o "cancelamento" do funcionamento de todos os *refresh tokens* existentes, bastando a aplicação incrementar o `count` em seu registro no banco de dados. Assim, uma vez que os *access tokens* (que têm, por definição, um curto tempo de vida) foram expirados, o *refresh token* não terá mais validade, impedindo a criação de novos tokens de acesso.

Note que quando eu digo "tempo de vida curto", me refiro a, no máximo, 5 minutos — e eu ainda acho muito, porque no caso de roubo, o *access token* levaria, no mínimo, 5 minutos para perder a validade, uma vez que o *refresh token* só é verificado novamente mediante a expiração do *access token*. O *refresh token*, por sua vez, pode ser mais longo. Normalmente, uso 1 semana, mas cabe a você decidir isso. :)

Comment: No seu exemplo, então, você muda o valor do `count` a cada uma semana, certo? (ou se o usuário cancelar). E em toda requisição o *client* estaria enviando os dois tokens para o servidor?

Comment: Depende da sua lógica. Mas não creio que isso esteja muito dentro do escopo dessa pergunta, já que você pergunta as _vantagens_, e não _como implementar_ (até porque se pedisse para implementar a pergunta seria muito ampla). Foi só um exemplo, o importante é entender o porquê e como funciona.

Comment: E caso um usuário malicioso capturar o refreshToken, como fica o segurança? Pois teoricamente ele poderia criar accesToken quando quiser

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno, isso é uma vulnerabilidade, claro. Mas não tem a ver com o que o refresh token realmente busca resolver. Isso representa o mesmo nível de ameaça se comparado a um token de sessão que fica em um cookie, por exemplo. Se for capturado maliciosamente, pode-se invadir a conta do usuário também. Claro que, em ambos os casos, medidas podem ser tomadas para prevenir esse tipo de problema (relacionar uma sessão ou _refresh token_ a um IP ou localização específica, a título de exemplo).