# Refresh de token com JWT e Node.JS

Tags: node.js, jwt

Estou fazendo uma API pra entender o funcionamento do **Json Web Token**, mas ele é muito simples sabe? Então não encontro um conteúdo de como fazer um refresh do token que dura apenas 5 minutos de um jeito que seria simples para mim entender.

Segue o código:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const app = express()

const SECRET= 'julioceno'

function verifyJwt(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.headers['x-access-token']

    const index = blackList.findIndex(item => { item === token})
    
    if (index !== -1) return res.status(401).end()

    jwt.verify(token, SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) return res.status(401).end()
    
        next()
    })

}

const blackList  = []


app
    .use(bodyParser.json())


    .get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.json({ message: "Tudo ok por aqui"})
    })

    .get('/clientes', verifyJwt,(req, res) => {
        res.json([{ id: 1, name: 'Júlião' }])
    })

    .post('/login', (req, res) => {
      
        if (req.body.user === 'julio' && req.body.password === 123) {
            const token = jwt.sign({userId: 1}, SECRET, {expiresIn: 300})

            return res.json({auth: true, token})
        }

        res.status(401).end()
    })


    .post('/logout', (req, res) => {
        blackList.push(req.headers['x-access-token'])
        res.end()
    })

    .listen(3000)
```

A função `verifyJwt` é um middleare que faz a verificação se o token é valido ou não ou se ele estiver presente na blacklist, o acesso da rota será negado.

A rota login é onde eu faço a autenticação e gero o token.

A rota `/clientes` é onde eu necessito do token, por que se vocês prestarem bem atenção o `verifyJwt` está ali entre os middlewares da rota, se estiver inválido o token eu não consigo usar.

No exemplo ai eu só queria uma forma de ir fazendo o refresh do token se o usuário ainda estiver usando o site (no caso a API).

Comment: Talvez isto responda à sua pergunta? [Qual a vantagem em usar um Refresh Token ao invés de somente o Access Token?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445480/69296)

Comment: Vale ressaltar que [há quem seja contra utilizar JWTs para autenticação](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/). E os argumentos são decentes.

Comment: Não mano, não é isso não, gostaria de saber como implementar um refresh ai no código entende? A questão da importância eu já entendi

Answer (score -2):

Para que o token JWT seja renovado sempre que o usuário recarregar a página, você pode criar um mecanismo para renovar o token a cada solicitação válida.

Aqui está um exemplo de como você pode implementar essa lógica de renovação do token:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();

const SECRET = 'julioceno';
const TOKEN_EXPIRATION = '300s'; // Tempo de expiração do token em segundos (5 minutos)

function verifyJwt(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.headers['x-access-token'];

    const index = blackList.findIndex(item => item === token);

    if (index !== -1) return res.status(401).end();

    jwt.verify(token, SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) return res.status(401).end();

        // Se o token é válido, você pode renová-lo e definir o novo token no cabeçalho da resposta.
        const newToken = jwt.sign({ userId: decoded.userId }, SECRET, { expiresIn: TOKEN_EXPIRATION });
        res.setHeader('x-access-token', newToken);

        next();
    });
}

const blackList = [];

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Tudo ok por aqui" });
});

app.get('/clientes', verifyJwt, (req, res) => {
    res.json([{ id: 1, name: 'Júlião' }]);
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.user === 'julio' && req.body.password === 123) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: 1 }, SECRET, { expiresIn: TOKEN_EXPIRATION });
        return res.json({ auth: true, token });
    }

    res.status(401).end();
});

app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
    blackList.push(req.headers['x-access-token']);
    res.end();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

No exemplo, quando um token é verificado como válido, um novo token com o mesmo ID de usuário é gerado. Isso atualiza automaticamente o token em cada solicitação válida (cada vez que houver algum tipo de navegação de página). Você pode ajustar o tempo de expiração (TOKEN_EXPIRATION), lembrando que o tempo é contado em segundos, sendo 300 = 5 minutos.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8842/137387

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).